# Fortran access / store data correctly in a nested loop

Tags: loops, fortran, iteration

I have a rather simple question on an iteration in a nested loop. I show the necessary code at the end.
The first iteration over the node dimension works fine. I do some calculation which results I store in T_int and P_int. But when I want to access the data in the second loop over the nobs dimension I can not handle to access the data. When I output the dimension of T_int it is correct as it has the length of nobs. But my print T_int within loop just shows the same value for every nobs respectively for each node. Can anyone give me a hint how to handle that? I have the feeling it must be rather easy, but I have not left any patience on that. So, I would be very grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance!

```
    ! Start loop over node dimension
    N = Solver%Mesh%NumberOfNodes
    Do ii=1,N

        SURF = SurfValues(SurfPerm(ii))

        !! Step 1: Interpolate AWS Station Data on grid - Temp all values, Prec only if /=0
        T_int = TEMPobs(ii) - ((SURF-aws) * lapseT)
        Where (PRECobs /= 0)
             P_int = PRECobs(ii) - ((SURF-aws) * lapseRRR)
        End Where
        print *,'Dimension T_int', size(T_int)

        ! Start loop over nobs dimension
        Do oo = 1,nobs

        print *,'Number of Node and  NOBS', ii,oo
             If (T_int(nobs) > 0) Then
                  T_mpl(nobs) = T_int(nobs)
             Else if (T_int(nobs) <= 0) Then
                  T_mpl(nobs) = 0
             End if
        print *,'T_int within loop', T_int(oo)

        End do
    End do
```

Comment: Without a complete program this is very difficult to answer, but I suspect you mean need an index on `T_int = TEMPobs(ii) - ((SURF-aws) * lapseT)` - as written it will set the whole of the T_int array to the same value. Is this it? Without more code (and you should *always* provide a complete but short program that sows the issue) I can't tell more

Comment: What even is this `T_int`? How exactly is it declared? What about the other symbols? See [mcve].